# Eclipse not recognising express/node

Tags: eclipse, node.js, express, nodeclipse

I have been using Linux for less than 24 hours, so please, if there is anymore information I should provide, do be quite specific about how to get that information.

I've been trying to install Node.js, express.js and eclipse. As you can see, ubuntu does recognise both node.js and express as installed on my system (I think!) and I got the Nodeclipse-extension for eclipse, but still Eclipse doesn't seem to recognise either node.js or express (see my image below). I also want to add that the time occurrence of the error, I was trying to build a Node.js Express Project.

[image]

**At this point, how do I go about debugging the situation?** The folder location shown in the image does not fully exist. I can only go as far as [...]/bin/ - I have been looking at error messages similar to mine, and it seems like people are getting such errors because they're lacking an installation, however, from my screenshot provided, I would think everything is installed as needed.

I am using a native 64-bit windows laptop with Linux (Ubuntu) installed through a virtualbox. Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS and just 32-bit, as I don't have spare 2 gb ram to give the 64-bit version. Sadness.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Windows -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse
check what is configured for Node and Express

Read more on http://www.nodeclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which worked for me:

**WINDOWS:**
I did double installations of the needed modules. They were both located in C:/Users/X/AppData/Roaming, in the Eclipse directories and finally in C:/Program Files/nodejs. When I deleted all the node_modules, besides critical ones for nodejs to function and then ran Eclipse with Nodeclipse, it seemed to function and Eclipse automaticly defined folders in its own subdirectory, in which Express were located.

**UBUNTU:**
Delete all node_modules files and run Eclipse with Nodeclipse. See the windows explanation for a more detailed overview. Same problem and solution seemed to be present for both systems. Do note that the file directories are of course not completely interchangeable. You'll need to locate your instances of node_module.